# Catch invalid character for XML entry

Tags: c#, xml

Inside a method to delete an employee: you type in the ID of the employee (see xml below for reference) you want to delete and it runs this code:

```
Console.Write("\r\nEnter the ID of the employee you wish to delete: ");
delId = Console.ReadLine();

    try
    {
        XmlNode t;
        t = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/employees/employee[@id=" + delId + "]");
```

If I type a correct ID, this happens:

```
t.ParentNode.RemoveChild(t);
xmldoc.Save(filepath);
```

If I type any characters such as ; ' " ` | into the console rather than a valid ID, it returns an exception, what /how should I use/ do to catch this and display an error?

My current catch in this method is:

```
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = pr.error;
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nError: " + ex.Message + "\r\n(that employee might not exist?)\r\n");
            pr.run(); // Restart 
    }
```

XML:

```
<employees>
  <employee name="Alastair Wilkins" id="1" />
  <employee name="Test Person" id="12345" />
</employees>
```

Comment: It's also really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: [MSDN article on SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx)
SelectSingleNode throws XPathException. It may help you to validate these characters  ; ' " ` |

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: Where is this question asking for code review? The question as written by the OP is "what /how should I use/ do to catch this and display an error?".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper was a bit too quick, never though he meant _another_ exception. And given that he knows how to catch exceptions...

Comment: @user3394380 - Catching an XPathException has fixed this, apologies for not reading the MSDN article. However I still need to catch for a NullReference, how to combine the two? Should I catch (Exception ex) and then write an if statement to determine what type of exception ex is?

Comment: Updated coded to add second exception and it is working, @user3394380 - provide your comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct, thank you.

Comment: @AlastairWilkins Thank you for accepting my answer. To combine multiple exceptions use 2 blocks `try{} catch(XPathException){} catch (NullReferenceException){}` :)

Comment: I actually caught (Exception ex) and then ran an if statement to determine what type of exception it was: `                if (ex is NullReferenceException)
                {
                    // stuff
                }
                else if (ex is XPathException)
                {
                    // stuff
                }`

Comment: OK. It works as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN article on SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx)

SelectSingleNode throws XPathException. It may help you to validate these characters ; ' " ` |